# Why does my code fail on this SIMPLE exercise?

Tags: python, arrays

I am doing a coding exercise:

*Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.*

***Example***

- For sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1], the output should be
  false;

  There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.
- For sequence = [1, 3, 2], the output should be
  true;

  You can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 2]. Alternately, you can remove 2 to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 3].

.

So I wrote this code:

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    first_list, second_list = [x for x in sequence], [x for x in sequence]
    for i in range(len(sequence)-1):
        if sequence[i] >= sequence[i+1]:
            first_list.remove(sequence[i])
            second_list.remove(sequence[i+1])
            break

    if first_list == sorted(set(first_list)) or second_list == sorted(set(second_list)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The code passes 13/15 tests.

Below are the 2 inputs that my code fails on:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]

[3, 5, 67, 98, 3]
```

Both inputs should return True but my code returns False. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the type of `sequence`? Is it a list?

Comment: Yes it's a list.

Comment: So what's the point of: `first_list, second_list = [x for x in sequence], [x for x in sequence]`?

Comment: The pythonic way to make a copy of a list is `first_list = sequence[:]`

Comment: @cezar the point of making two copies of the lists were to be able to compare them later on.

Comment: @Barmar Sweet, will keep that in mind!

Comment: Which debugger are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [list.remove](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]
>>> l.remove(3)
>>> print(l)
[1, 2, 4, 3, 6]
```

Instead of `remove(value)`, use `pop(index)`:

```
first_list.pop(i)
second_list.pop(i+1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, was stuck on this exercise for atleast a couple of hours and your explanation was absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Take your first list, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]`. Once you run the for loop over `first_list` and `second_list`, the values of those variables are:

```
In [9]: first_list
Out[9]: [1, 2, 3, 3, 6]

In [10]: second_list
Out[10]: [1, 2, 4, 3, 6]
```

The first part of the `if` is `False` because:

```
In [12]: sorted(set(first_list))
Out[12]: [1, 2, 3, 6]
```

By putting the list into a set, you've lost one of the 3's.

The second part of the `if` is `False` because `second_list` is not sorted.

So, both parts of the `if` statement are `False`, and your function returns `False`.

Comment: Well, after the for loop, the first list becomes, like you said, [1, 2, 3, 3, 6]. However, the second list should become: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6] right? Since we are removing the element at index 4 (i+1). In which case it equals to sorted(set([1, 2, 3, 4, 6)) and the function should return True. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Oh never mind, the answer by Tomasz explained why I am wrong and you are right.

Comment: The full answer is a combination of this answer and @Tomasz.